# Awk with 2 files and if statement?

Tags: awk

I have been struggling with this task.

I have 2 files:

File 1:

```
London
Milan
Paris
```

File 2:

```
London
```

Desired output file:

```
London Present
Milan Absent
Paris Absent
```

Essentially the task is simple: I want to reprint File 1 (in the same exact order) and add a column where I say "present" if the term is present on file 2, or "absent" if it is not.

I have been trying with awk but I cannot do it.

Comment: There are quite a few (hundreds) of examples for such awks in SO, you should search some. _I have been trying with awk_ also, we'd like to see some trials, please. Now my downvote, btw.

Comment: _Not_, not _now_, lol.

Comment: I searched some, but I cannot find a solution that does exactly what I want. I don't mind of the down vote anyway, I know how this site works and that's why I try to use it as less as possible. I was trying whit a similar answer, but replacing "absent" with 0 but cannot make it work. This for example: join -a 1 -e 0 -t $'\t' -o 1.1,2.2 F1.txt F2.tx (first I add an extra column with 1 (meaning Present) to my file 2 format shown above). Then I was messing around with awk with commands such as:

Comment: while read p; do
awk -v var="$p" 'BEGIN{if ($p == $1) {print "present"} else { print "Absent"}}' file2.txt

done < file1.txt

Comment: But I know the awk code above is wrong.

Comment: Next time, please add trials to the original question. You will end up with a lot less comments and downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is an exact awk to solve your problem. I hope it helps:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                                   # process file2
    a[$1]                                   # hash first field
    next                                    # on to next record
}
{                                           # process file1
    print $1,(($1 in a)?"Present":"Absent") # print field and presense in a hash
}' file2 file1                              # mind the order
```

Output:

```
London Present
Milan Absent
Paris Absent
```

If the words in your files have space in them, consider changing `$1`s to `$0`s.